# Page object gem with Bootstrap

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, page-object-gem

I have been using the Ruby page object gem successfully for the last few months, however the new software I'm testing is using Bootstrap so it has become harder.

e.g I'm trying to select from a dropdown, which is normally simple, but with Bootstrap the original HTML isn't visible to the driver:

```html
<select class="currency-selector" style="display: none;">
    <option value="GLOBAL">All</option>
    <option selected="" value="GBP">GBP</option>
</select>
```

So this isn't working.

```
select_list(:original_currency, :class => 'currency-selector')
```

What is visible to the driver is all the Bootstrap generated code which looks more like this:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu" style="max-height: 164.5px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 80px;">
    <li rel="0">
    <li class="selected" rel="1">
        <a class="" style="" tabindex="0">
            <span class="text">GBP</span>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li rel="2">
    <li rel="3">
</ul>
```

Is there a nice way around this problem and still using the page object gem or will I be forced to use selenium more directly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use ID's instead of class selectors?  I looked over at the page object gem (as I use capybara as my alternative) and it seems straightforward.

```
select_list(:original_currency, :id => "currency-list")
```

Next you'd just add that ID to your HTML

```
<select class="currency-selector" style="display: none;" id="currency-list">
    <option value="GLOBAL">All</option>
    <option selected="" value="GBP">GBP</option>
</select>
```

You're right that bootstrap generates a lot so I think ID's will make your tests less brittle.

Comment: the locator tags arent the issue, the issue is that the bootstrap makes the select html not visible to the driver,

the gem looks for <select> and <option> tags to work , but these are not visible and are instead replaced by<div> <ul> and <li> like in the code posted above

Comment: Bootstrap is replacing a select box with an ul?  Can I see the form that's generating the select box?  Are you using form_for? simple_form_for?

Comment: yeah, so the html i posted above with the <select> tag is the original html, and then the html you interact with is an unordered list, if you use firebug to inspect the code the original html can still be seen but is greyed out, as it is not visible on the page, i'm testing this application not developing it but ill try and get that form